# Nested Linq Group By

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, nested

What I have: List

Class: Rule
   -->
   Class: Term
   --->
   Property Compare_Src
   Property Compare_Mode

What I want to do:
use a Linq statement to get my Rules, grouped by a Combination of its Compare_Src and Compare_Mode.

Static Example for one Combination: (Here I get a list for all rules with Compare_src = EmpfaengerToken and Compare_mode = equals. What I want is a full list with all rules, grouped by the two propertys, instead of hardcoded values.

```
            var regeln_empfaengertoken  = 
        (
            from rule in rules 
            where 
            (
                from term in rule.Term 
                    where 
                    (
                        term.Compare_src == Entities.Enums.Compare_src.EmpfaengerToken
                        &&
                        term.Compare_mode.ToString() == "equals"
                    )
                    select term
            ).Count() > 0 
            select rule
        ).ToList<Entities.Rule>();
```

I know it's possible, but can't find the right solution :(

```
  [Serializable]
public class Rule
{
    private List<Term> _term = new List<Term>();
    ...
}


   [Serializable]
public class Term
{
    private Entities.Enums.Compare_src _compare_src;
    private Entities.Enums.Compare_mode _compare_mode;
    private Entities.Enums.Compare_Type _compare_type;
    .........
 }
```

Comment: Can you give the code of your classes to?

Comment: Code of the classes is alot of data stuff.. its just XML serialization classes.

Comment: But write the classes down anyway... it makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: Also, providing simple sample data in the form... What you have --> What you want might also help.

Comment: I have a list of rules who contain a List of Terms. A term has a compare_source and a compare_mode.

I need to group the rules by the compare_source and compare_mode.

Comment: Do you want to group strictly on Rules or the combination of a Rule and Term? Otherwise, what do you want to do if a Rule has two Terms with differing compare_source and/or compare_mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
rules.SelectMany(rule => rule.Term)
     .GroupBy(term => new { term.Compare_src, term.Compare_mode })
     .Select(termGroup => 
           new {
              Key = termGroup.key, 
              Rules = rules.Where(r => r.Term.Any(t => 
                 t.Compare_src == termGroup.key.Compare_src && 
                 t.Compare_mode == termGroup.key.Compare_mode
              )
               }
             )
```

What I did here (tried anyway, didn't check if this actually works with your model) is to inverse the query. First get all the terms, group them by the mutiple field key and then select the relevant rules for each group.

Comment: Seems to go in the right direction... but i get an IEnumerable<Boolean> for Rules = rules.Select(r => r.Term.An<(t => ...........................)

Comment: My bad... `.Select ` should have been `.Where`, updated the code.

Comment: Great... first test seemed to give exactly what I wanted... and this is a brilliant way to solve it. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help... Isn't Linq one of the most amazing things ever?

Comment: Yeah it is :-) This would have taken ages of delegate searching with common .NET. Sometimes it's tricky, but it opens new possibilities when working with complicated object architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't a single group by suffice? You can group by multiple terms using an anonymous class:

```
var ruleGroups = from rule in rules 
                 group by new { rule.Term.Compare_src, rule.Term.Compare_mode } 
                 into g
                 select ...;
```

This would give you an `IGrouping` though that you can convert to a list of lists, you could flatten this structure using `SelectMany()`:

```
var orderedRuleList = ruleGroups.SelectMany( x => x)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Because Term is a List<rule.Term>. This would only work if Term was an Instance of rule.Term.

Comment: @Steav: You can use `SelectMany` to flatten a structure like `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` into a single `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write write-only code. I know it is tempting to go off on this syntactic sugar for lambdas and extension methods, but I'd advice to assign intermediate results to temporary holders.

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
group term by new { term.Compare_src, term.Compare_mode }
```

Comment: that would group the terms, yes. But I need to group the rules by the term propertys (that's why it's nested).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you want since the example is not quite so clear. Have you looked at these two resources? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) and [101 Linq examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746).

If you are more precise in your question it would be easier to help you.